# Why guides option is not working in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I recently installed Adobe Photoshop CS6 and the guides option is not working. I need help. Also, I am new at Photoshop so a step-by-step tutorial will be appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Problem with guides in Photoshop]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guides option is not selectable because you have no guides created.

To create guides:

- Your rulers are already activated, but if they weren't you'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to show them.
- Click on the ruler and drag it out to wherever you want the guide to go.
- Now go back to your dialog. `Guides` is no longer grayed out.

You can find things like this by searching "[create guides in photoshop](http://www.bing.com/search?form=MOZPSB&pc=MOZO&q=create+guides+in+photoshop)" or something similar.